# API Retorna Objeto Json com ID - IONIC 5 e Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic

Estou trabalhando com uma API que retorna um JSON com um objeto JSON dentro.
Exemplo:

```
{"authorized":true,"status":200,"foundmatch":true,"requested":"baiier",
"players": {
        "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083": {
            "profile": {
                "p_id": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                "p_name": "BaIIer",
                "p_user": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                "p_platform": "uplay",
                "verified": true
            },
```

Eu preciso acessar esses objetos que estao dentro do objeto players, porem o primeiro objeto que ele retorna é um ID ou seja diferente para cada tipo de consulta, e eu não estou conseguindo acessar esse objeto.
Meu serviço:

```
obterNickname(nickname: string){
    let url = 'https://r6.apitab.com/search/uplay/' + nickname;
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise();
  }
```

Meu retorno:

```
nickname : string = "";
NicknameResult : any = {ranked:'', status:'', idNick:''};

constructor(private r6Service : R6Service) {}

  consultarNickname() {
    this.r6Service.obterNickname(this.nickname)
    .then((json) =>{
      this.NicknameResult = (json);
      this.IdResult = (this.NicknameResult.players)
      console.log(json)
    }) 
    .catch((erro) => {
      console.log(erro);
    });
  }
```

Meu html:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Nickname:
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="nickname"></ion-input>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
    </ion-label>  
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-button expand="block" (click)="consultarNickname()">
      Consultar
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <p>Nickname: </p>
    {{NicknameResult.requested}}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <p>Ranked: </p>
    {{NicknameResult.players}}
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Igor!

Para chegar no objeto `players` você pode fazer a buscar por partes do objeto que você recuperou antes.

Como sugestão eu fiz assim:

```
let obj = {
            "authorized":true,
            "status":200,
            "foundmatch":true,
            "requested":"baiier",
            "players": {
                    "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083": {
                        "profile": {
                            "p_id": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                            "p_name": "BaIIer",
                            "p_user": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                            "p_platform": "uplay",
                            "verified": true
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Como você já sabe que o objeto capturado já tem o atributo `players` você pode ler os atributos dele

```
let obj1 =  Object.keys(obj.players)
//Vai retornar assim [ '9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083' ] 
let obj2 = obj1[0]
```

Após isso você tem acesso ao conteúdo do valor `9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083` assim:

```
obj.players[obj2]
```

```js
let obj = {
            "authorized":true,
            "status":200,
            "foundmatch":true,
            "requested":"baiier",
            "players": {
                    "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083": {
                        "profile": {
                            "p_id": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                            "p_name": "BaIIer",
                            "p_user": "9bd44bde-9c48-48ae-9c2b-4e11e4b16083",
                            "p_platform": "uplay",
                            "verified": true
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

let obj1 =  Object.keys(obj.players)
console.log('Obj1', obj1);
let obj2 = obj1[0]



console.log( 'atributos', obj.players[obj2] );
```

Espero que ajude!